# JavaScript RegExp set index manually

Tags: javascript, regex

What if you want to match string from some known position?
Then you have to slice this string from that position and only after this you can do matching.
But what if string is very big, and you don't want to slice it many times, cause it will produce many new strings, this is bad for memory, for execution time.
I wonder, why there is index argument in `String.indexOf` and no such capabilities for `String.search` and all RegExp methods?

```
var rgx1 = /some pattern/g
var rgx2 = /other pattern/
var match = rgx1.exec(VeryBigString)
if (match !== null) {
  rgx2.lastIndex = match.index
  var result = rgx2.exec(VeryBigString)
}
```

Here I tried to set `lastIndex` property, but no success. Regexp has this property, but does not want to accept changes on it.

Comment: I've looked for native libraries for node.js that could do regexp's better, but did not find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set [`RegExp#lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property of the regular expression.

```js
var regExp = /a/g,
    result,
    string = 'aaaaaaaa';

regExp.lastIndex = 4;

while ((result = regExp.exec(string)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Found ${result[0]}. Next starts at ${regExp.lastIndex}.`);
}
```

Comment: Did not mention `^` pattern in my regexp :)
lastIndex works